# Android listview background color onitemclick

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am setting the visibility of a button as VISIBLE or GONE on item click. The problem is when the first time I clicked on a item, the listview is reloading. And the next times it's not.

That's why I can't fix the background color on first time item clicked but i need to click two times on a item to fix the background color. The next times the background color is fixed by forcing the background color in my "onItemClick" function.

When i delete "setvisible" on the clicklistener, the problem disapear. I want to know why my view is reloading ? I can see this by fixing a log on my adapter.

```
public class MallListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data_list;
    Context context;

    public MallListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data)
    {
        super();
        data_list = data;
        context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) 
    {
        Log.d(Config.DebugTAG,"Get view");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_listview_row, null);        
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.state_txt);

        tv1.setText(data_list.get(pos).get(3));

        TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_name);
        tv2.setText(data_list.get(pos).get(0));

        TextView tv3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.last_date);
        String tokenDate[] = data_list.get(pos).get(1).split("/");
        String date_t = tokenDate[1]+"/"+tokenDate[2];
        tv3.setText(date_t);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return data_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) 
    {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) 
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Here is the code of my listview

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
      mall_data = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_shops);
      setListView();
}

public void setListView()
{
     MallListAdapter adapter = new MallListAdapter(this, sqlLiteData);
     mall_data.setAdapter(adapter);
     mall_data.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
     {
        int last_position=0;
        @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
         {

             select_line = sqlLiteData.get(position).get(2); // id_shop
             select_date = sqlLiteData.get(position).get(1); // Date
             type_evt   = sqlLiteData.get(position).get(3); // type evt
             id_n_evt   = sqlLiteData.get(position).get(4); // id_
             if(type_evt.equals("F")){
                 add_date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }else{
                 add_date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
             mall_data.getItemAtPosition(0);
             edit_conc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             if(list_id.get(position).equals(id_user) || admin_user.equals("1")){
                 delete_conc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
             //here I force background color                        
             parent.getChildAt(last_position).setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
             parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor((android.R.color.holo_blue_light)));
             last_position  = position;
         }
});
```

Comment: Can you try `add_date.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` instead `GONE`

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But i finally find a solution. I do not use setvisibility anymore. I display all buttons and then I disable or enable the button (depends on the selected item) with "setEnable(true)" and "setEnable(false)".

Comment: Yes you can do that if you want to show button in disable, otherwise `INVISIBLE` does not show button but keep the view space